# Including file with backward slash is won't work in PHP?

Tags: php

Am running scripts using command-line .

Backward include path is doesn't work for me

```
eg: require("../../../../test.php"); 
(But in browser it works)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

`dirname(__FILE__);` will give you real path to current directory and you're then about le to include your file

```
require(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../../../test.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, the base path should be the directory from which you are calling php. When running in the browser (through apache, etc) the calling path should be the webroot directory.

So you should specify the directory of the current script or call it from its own directory.

For instance:

```
require(__DIR__."../../../../test.php");
```

**DIR** is a PHP Magic Constant (http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) which returns the directory of the currently running file.

Comment: isn't that same answer as I wrote?

Comment: It is similar, but it's cleaner and actually explained. Also, there were no answers when I started to write mine.

Comment: There's ajax control each minute, it probably noticed you about my answer